# Swift crash related to "ProcessOutOfLineJob"

Tags: swift, crash, actor

I wrote up the problem here on the Swift forum, and I still haven't been able to find the cause: https://forums.swift.org/t/help-understanding-very-cryptic-crash-report-from-testflight-mach-msg2-trap/64791

I will be so grateful to anyone who can give some grain of additional insight, because I can't reproduce the crash locally and so I'm quite stuck.

Thank you!